# É possível fazer o poster image da tag <video> ser renderizada somente se o vídeo der erro?

Tags: html

Ao utilizar a tag Html video, ilustrado no exemplo abaixo:

```
<video class="video-block__video" preload="none" poster="{url-da-imagem}" loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="{url-do-video}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Percebo que, ao dar refresh na página,poster image aparece por menos de 1 segundo, e depois o vídeo (depois que a página carrega).

Existe alguma forma de impedir que a imagem apareça, antes de a página ser carregada, semelhante ao que temos no preload="none" para o video?

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar Javascript para esperar que a página carregue e depois adicionar o elemento de video à página.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var html = `<video class="video-block__video" preload="none" poster="{url-da-imagem}" loop muted playsinline>
                            <source src="{url-do-video}" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>`
            $("body").append(html);
        });
    </script>
```